# forecast differenced series in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm new on R, I've always use e-views and now I have to do a regression

I have Xt stationary and Yt not stationary so I need to difference

`yt=Yt-Y(t-1)`

then the regression is

`yt = a + bXt`

how can I do the forecast on R and obtain the "real" value and not the differences?

in e-views is enouth to write `d(Yt)` but in R is impossible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding lagged variables to an lm model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096787/adding-lagged-variables-to-an-lm-model)

Comment: my dependent variable (`yt`) is not lagged, it is differenced

Comment: You can use the function `diff()` to calculate the differences.

Comment: sure but when I do the forecast, the function give me the differenced forecast value

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is `cumsum`, which is the inverse operation of `diff` (almost).  You can recover a vector from its differences like this:

```
> z<-sample(20)
> dz<-diff(z)
> z0<-cumsum(c(z[1],dz))
> all(z==z0)
[1] TRUE
```

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
dY<-diff(Y)
dYhat<-lm(dY ~ X[-1])$fitted
Yhat<-cumsum(c(Y[1],dYhat))
```

Answer (score 4):

First, if you think X affects y, then you should difference *both* variables. Differencing only one of them leads to a model where X affects the *change* in y rather than y itself.

You could do this with the `arima()` function (and differencing both variables):

```
fit <- arima(y, xreg=X, order=c(0,1,0))
```

Then predictions on the undifferenced scale are obtained using

```
fcast <- predict(fit, n.ahead=10, newxreg=futureX)
```

where `futureX` contains the next 10 values of X.

If you really wanted to model the affect of X on d(y), then create a new variable

```
sumX <- cumsum(X)
```

and use that instead of `X` in the fit (and similarly modify `futureX`).

Answer (score 0):

If you forecast the first difference h many days ahead, you have an estimate of how higher or lower the series will be in h many days. You just to add the last observed value to this difference to get the level:

```
dy_{t}:= y_{t} - y_{t-1}
```

You forecast `dy_{T+h}`, you know the last observation, `y_{T}, so y_{T+h} = dy_{T+h} + y_{T}`. Just augment all forecasts of the future value by the last observation and you get a level forecast.

If you used the first difference of logarithms, `dlny_{t} := lny_{t} - lny_{t-1}`, you have a first order Taylor approximation to a growth rate, so you'd forecasting growth rates. In that case, level forecasts would be `y_{T+h} = (1+dlny_{T+h}) y_{T}`.

You don't need any complicated function to do those transformations. In fact, because `y_{T}` is a scalar, if you have a vector for `dy_{T+h} or dlny_{T+h}` for all `h`, `R` will allow you to write the expressions I wrote above using scalars and vectors and `R` will manage dimension problems correctly on its own.